# set_value not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the form_validation library loaded in my controller and the form validation itself is working, but when using set_value() it's not populating the form fields. Here is the code in to controller:

```
function addUser()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstName', 'firstname', 'trim|required|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('surname', 'surname', 'trim|required|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emailAddress', 'email address', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]|max_length[255]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|max_length[20]|min_length[5]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwordVerify', 'password verification', 'trim|required|max_length[20]|min_length[5]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('formValidationError',  validation_errors('<p class="error">', '</p>'));
        redirect('/member/register');
    } else {
        echo 'Passed';
    }
}
```

And here is the code in the view:

```
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('formValidationError'); ?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('member/addUser'); ?>">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create a FREE account</legend>
        <div>
            <label for="firstName">Firstname</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo set_value('firstName'); ?>" maxlength="30">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="surname">Surname</label>
            <input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo set_value('surname'); ?>" maxlength="30">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="emailAddress">Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="emailAddress" value="<?php echo set_value('emailAddress'); ?>" maxlength="255">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="20">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="passwordVerify">Verify Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="passwordVerify" maxlength="20">
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Is there something I am missing? Is the redirect causing the issue?

Comment: How is it no working? It's supposed to re-fill the fields after validation fails. And why are you redirecting to another page if the form is not validly filled? If I miss a field do I need to register again? :)

Comment: @DamienPirsy The form fields are not populating. The user is redirected back to the registration page if they miss a field. The reason I redirect is because I don't want the user to see the /register/addUser url in the address bar (which is what would happen if I loaded the view rather than redirect).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not working because you are using redirection.

Instead of

```
    $this->session->set_flashdata('formValidationError',  validation_errors('<p class="error">', '</p>'));
    redirect('/member/register');
```

just for testing, try to load the view

```
    $this->load->view('member_register_view');
```

and you will see.

`set_value` requires that the form validation ran in the same context... you lose this context when you redirect.

Comment: I don't want to load the view because I want to preserve the URLs. For example, I don't want to users to see /members/addUser in their address bar upon error, I want them to go back to /register

Comment: I will have to set flash data for this purpose I'd imagine.

Comment: Why not `<form action="/member/register">` and at `function register()` you just `if (!empty($_POST)) return $this->addUser();`?

Comment: The problem with that is that when a user tries to reload the page after sending the form and getting an error, they will see the typical 'Do you want to send the post data again?' type of message which is not so nice. It is better to redirect the user after performing a post request.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue with `redirect()`, i used `$this->session->set_flashdata('field','value')` to store data before redirect, as loading view was not possible in my case, and reused it as value of input tag, 
`<input type='text' value='<?= $this->session->flashdata('field') ?>' >`